# Calling multiple popen in c/c++

Tags: c, unix, process, freebsd, popen

I'm using FreeBSD and C/C++ to control the robot.
Here is the issue:

I use `popen()` in writing mode to give the command to computer in order to control the robot. So now I want to get the output of the command so I create another `popen()` in reading mode to get it.

Will it work?

Should I create some kind of parent and child process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So now I want to get the output of the command so I create another
>   popen() in reading mode to get it.

No, creating an additional stream using `popen(3)` won't work. However, since you are using FreeBSD you're in luck: on FreeBSD pipes are bidirectional, so **`popen(3)` accepts an `r+` argument**. From [the manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=popen&sektion=3):

> Since `popen()` is now implemented using a bidirectional pipe, the type
>   argument may request a **bidirectional data flow**.The type argument is a
>   pointer to a null-terminated string which must be 'r' for reading, 'w'
>   for writing, or **'r+' for reading and writing**.

So you will probably get away with simply reading the output from the same `FILE *`, with something like `fgets(3)`.